# Exposing VPC/API gateway to a specific DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway, slack-api, amazon-vpc

I have a `slack bot` which is running on a `EC2` in a `VPC`.

The `VPC`/ `API gateway` is supposed to only be exposed to slack (for slack event listening), Its not supposed to be publicly accessible.

How would I filter based on slack's `DNS`? `https://api.slack.com/robots`

I saw that `API gateway` has [resource policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies.html) however they are only `IP`\ `AWS account`\ `VPC` based.

Any other `AWS` services that can help?

Answer (score 1):

If the only reason you're exposing it to the web is for Slack to access it, then you could try using [Socket Mode](https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/socket), which pushes all the Slack traffic to websockets, meaning you don't need a public endpoint anymore.